# Microsoft.ReportDesigner, but it is loaded(?)

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with dll's

I Get this error when i go to the win form designer in my prodject

[image: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportDesigner, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"]

But in References i have loaded the requested reference dll from the IDE VisualStudio 10.0 Folder

[image: Loaded Dll props]

There must be something more that I'm missing. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the problem all i need was some lunch...

In my GAC folder on the development machine there are 2 diffrent version registerd
[image: Solution step 1]

and then i moved the ddl file from the first folder and moved it to the other folder

[image: Solution step 2]

This is most surely wrong and far from best practice, so i set my awnser as the correct one for now.
But i will keep reading the other awnsers and se if they fix this problem and then change it accordingly :)